# PHP read JSON Array with unknown variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, call

I have a Json Script with an Array inside and Array which looks like this shortened:

```
Array
(

    [assets] => Array
        (

            [CGGD.AS] => Array
                (
                    [shortName] => iShares Global Govt Bond Climat
                    [sector] => 
                    [industry] => 
                    [country] => 
                    [longBusinessSummary] => 
                    [currency] => USD
                    [marketCap] => 
                    [logo_url] => 
                    [Anlageklasse] => Anleihen
                    [Anmerkungen] => Staatsanleihen Welt
                    [Nachhaltigkeit] => 1
                    [Ist_Alternative] => 1
                    [weights] => 0.86563025602977
                )

            [SUOE.MI] => Array
                (
                    [shortName] => ISHARES EUR CORP BOND SRI UCITS
                    [sector] => 
                    [industry] => 
                    [country] => 
                    [longBusinessSummary] => 
                    [currency] => EUR
                    [marketCap] => 
                    [logo_url] => 
                    [Anlageklasse] => Anleihen
                    [Anmerkungen] => Unternehmensnaleihen EUR
                    [Nachhaltigkeit] => 1
                    [Ist_Alternative] => 1
                    [weights] => -0.47997445382071
                )

        )

    [risk] => 0.05323390949106
    [return] => 1.1125842376311
)
```

Now I want to work with the single variables shortName, industry, etc.
When I tried to call the function with

```
print_r($json_data['assets']['CGGD.AS']['shortName']);
```

it worked perfectly fine. When I use

```
print_r($_POST['assets'][0][0]);
```

it is not working at all and gives me the following warning:

> Warning: Undefined array key "assets" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\ergebnisdarstellung.php on line 52
>
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\ergebnisdarstellung.php on line 52

The problem I have is that I will not know what name will be in the second brackets like CGGD.AS and because of this I can not use the working function. I will not now how long the array is either and numbers are not working. Because of this I do not know how to call the single variabless without using the name.
How can I call the function?

Comment: Why are you switching from accessing `$json_data['assets']` to `$_POST['assets']`?

Comment: You have `$json_data` and `$_POST`, are they the same? You won't get request payload into `$_POST` when you use JSON as content-type.

Comment: If you don't know what keys are contained in an array - then _loop over it_. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I looked up if I could find any help, $POSt['assets'] was the result of it, but it is not working too if I change it to print_r($json_data['assets'][0][0]);

Comment: Look at it another way: Why would you _expect_ `$_POST["assets"]` to return anything? The data is in `$json_data`. Do you understand what `$_POST` is? Do you understand that different variables will contain different values? When using examples you've found, blindly copying and pasting is not a good approach, you need to think how the example might apply to _your_ situation and adjust accordingly. If you don't understand the code, take it apart bit by bit until you do.

Comment: Anyway yes, CBroe is correct, if you don't know what the names of the keys in the array are going to be in advance, then simply loop over the keys to output each value.

Comment: `it is not working too if I change it to print_r($json_data['assets'][0][0]);`...again, **think**: why would you _expect_ that to work? Does your array have a key named `0`? Clearly not. Stop guessing and actually look at your data and code properly. And also maybe make sure you understand the basics of arrays, and what a key is.

Comment: The "JSON" in your question is just a distraction: Once you decode JSON, you only have a nested `array`/`stdClass` data structure. Calling this data structure `$json_data` isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `shortName` you can [loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) your array:

```php
foreach ($json_data['assets'] as $key => $data) {
    print_r($data['shortName']);
}
```

If you want just `shortName` of first element, then use [`current`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```php
$item = current($json_data['assets']);

print_r($item['shortName']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [
    'assets' => [
        'CGGD.AS' => [
            'shortName'           => 'iShares Global Govt Bond Climat',
            // other fields omitted
        ],
        'SUOE.MI' => [
            'shortName'           => 'ISHARES EUR CORP BOND SRI UCITS',
            // other fields omitted
        ]
    ],
    'risk'   => 0.05323390949106,
    'return' => 1.1125842376311
];

$assetsKeys = array_keys($arr['assets']);
$shortNames = array_column($arr['assets'], 'shortName');
$result = array_combine($assetsKeys, $shortNames);

print_r($result);

// This will print:
// Array
// (
//     [CGGD.AS] => iShares Global Govt Bond Climat
//     [SUOE.MI] => ISHARES EUR CORP BOND SRI UCITS
// )
```